# SAM local start-api CORS issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services

I am using AWS CDK (Typescript) and running SAM local start-api to spin up an API tied to lambda resolvers and am running into a CORS issue when trying to hit the API from a browser. Here is my code:

### lambda config

```
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import {
  IResource,
  LambdaIntegration,
  MockIntegration,
  PassthroughBehavior,
  RestApi,
} from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-apigateway';
import {
  NodejsFunction,
  NodejsFunctionProps,
} from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda-nodejs';
import { Runtime } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda';

import { join } from 'path';
import * as lambda from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda';
import * as s3 from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-s3';
import * as ec2 from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2';
import * as rds from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-rds';
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';

export function addCorsOptions(apiResource: IResource) {
  apiResource.addMethod(
    'OPTIONS',
    new MockIntegration({
      integrationResponses: [
        {
          statusCode: '200',
          responseParameters: {
            'method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers':
              "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,X-Amz-User-Agent'",
            'method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "'*'",
            'method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Credentials':
              "'false'",
            'method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods':
              "'OPTIONS,GET,PUT,POST,DELETE'",
          },
        },
      ],
      passthroughBehavior: PassthroughBehavior.NEVER,
      requestTemplates: {
        'application/json': '{"statusCode": 200}',
      },
    }),
    {
      methodResponses: [
        {
          statusCode: '200',
          responseParameters: {
            'method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers': true,
            'method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods': true,
            'method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
            'method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin': true,
          },
        },
      ],
    }
  );
}

export class FrontendService extends Construct {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string) {
    super(scope, id);

    const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, 'HospoFEVPC');
    const cluster = new rds.ServerlessCluster(this, 'AuroraHospoFECluster', {
      engine: rds.DatabaseClusterEngine.AURORA_POSTGRESQL,
      parameterGroup: rds.ParameterGroup.fromParameterGroupName(
        this,
        'ParameterGroup',
        'default.aurora-postgresql10'
      ),
      defaultDatabaseName: 'hospoFEDB',
      vpc,
      scaling: {
        autoPause: cdk.Duration.seconds(0),
      },
    });

    const bucket = new s3.Bucket(this, 'FrontendStore');

    const nodeJsFunctionProps: NodejsFunctionProps = {
      environment: {
        BUCKET: bucket.bucketName,
        CLUSTER_ARN: cluster.clusterArn,
        SECRET_ARN: cluster.secret?.secretArn || '',
        DB_NAME: 'hospoFEDB',
        AWS_NODEJS_CONNECTION_REUSE_ENABLED: '1',
      },
      runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_14_X,
    };

    const registerLambda = new NodejsFunction(this, 'registerFunction', {
      entry: 'dist/lambda/register.js',
      memorySize: 1024,
      ...nodeJsFunctionProps,
    });

    const registerIntegration = new LambdaIntegration(registerLambda);

    const api = new RestApi(this, 'frontend-api', {
      restApiName: 'Frontend Service',
      description: 'This service serves the frontend.',
    });

    const registerResource = api.root.addResource('register');
    registerResource.addMethod('POST', registerIntegration);
    addCorsOptions(registerResource);
  }
}
```

### lambda resolver

```
export async function handler(event: any, context: any) {
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
      body: JSON.stringify(body),
    };
}
```

When I deploy the function to AWS and try hitting the endpoint from the live URL it works fine without any CORS issue, so it looks like the error may be with the SAMS-CLI. How can I get around this?

### Edit

Here is an image from the terminal where you can see the failed `OPTIONS` request.

[image]

Comment: can you add your globals config?

Comment: Suspect the error involves `addCorsOptions()`. Can you try what I put in my answer? Sorry it is not a clear case the answer will work, but it is also too long to be a comment.

Comment: Your code as linked above is fully working, I've just spent an hour setting it up - can you please add the `login` endpoint route to your code? Your error is regarding `login` but it is not in the code.

Comment: And please add the output of `sam local start-api --debug` in full. I also assume `/login` is routed to another Lambda (which isn't `register.js` as above)? I would hate for your bounty to go wasted so I'll follow this question to be able to help.

Comment: yes thats right /login is routed to a login lambda. Sorry I should have matched the console output with the correct lambda however it would still be the same outcome anyway

Comment: @redhouse87 it wouldn’t - you probably most likely have an issue with how you’re mapping your lambdas. the sample you have above is working completely fine (i’ve manually verified your exact code above). the issue stems from surrounding code so if you could please share demo handler code for login and also add how you’re mapping login, that’s be great.

Comment: as it is right now, your problem isn’t reproducible with the code you’ve placed.

Comment: @redhouse87 Or feel free to change the output to the error you get with the above code - but the above code is 100% working.

Comment: I am now voting to close this question as irreproducible, as I can manually verify that the code above is completely 100% working using the latest version of `sam` running `sam local start-api`  and does not produce the output that OP has specified.

Answer (score -2):

As per [this docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/aws-apigateway-readme.html), you don't need to manually configure the pre-flight OPTIONS method.

For example,

```
new apigateway.RestApi(this, 'api', {
  defaultCorsPreflightOptions: {
    allowOrigins: apigateway.Cors.ALL_ORIGINS,
    allowMethods: apigateway.Cors.ALL_METHODS // this is also the default
  }
})
```

Then you can do away with the manual `addCorsOptions()`.

Comment: This is not the correct answer

Comment: @redhouse87 The error you posted confirms my suspicion something is not correct in the OPTIONS method. What's wrong with the answer?

Comment: I don't think SAM spins up a local API instance when you run sam local start API